# Show explicitly the rational function field over the fixed field is not Galois.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

For complex number field $\mathbb{C}$, we can consider the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}(x))$. It's not hard to show $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}(x))\simeq \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$. Since we have a continuous quotient map $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C}) $, then the number of connected component is $1$ or $2$. However, from infinite Galois theory, the Galois group must be a profinite group, which is totally disconnected. Therefore, $\mathbb{C}(x)/\mathbb{C}(x)^{\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})}$ is not a Galois extension.

I want to ask if we can construct some subextensions and closed subgroups that condradict to the Galois correspondence? The subextensions of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ are easy to understand, i.e., all of the form $\mathbb{C}(Q(x))$, but how about the closed subgroups?

Comment: $\sigma(x)=x+1$ is an automorphism, $\{ \sigma^n(x),n\in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is infinite, so $\Bbb{C}(x)/\Bbb{C}(x)^\sigma$ is not algebraic (indeed $\Bbb{C}(x)^\sigma=\Bbb{C}$). Closed subgroup according to what topology? There is no Krull topology on $PGL_2(\Bbb{C})$ since $\mathbb{C}(x)/\mathbb{C}(x)^{\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})}$ is not an infinite tower of finite extensions.

Comment: @reuns Just the usual topology. I didn't realize that $\mathbb{C}(x)^{\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})}$ before you point out. Under this observation, I think we can conclude that every closed subgroup of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ of finite index doesn't have corresponding extension.

Comment: I think that Galois theory only discusses algebraic extensions. Sure, we can still discuss the group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$ when $L/K$ is transcendental. But even in infinite Galois theory (with the Krull topology, profinite groups and all that jazz) we require $L/K$ to be algebraic. Equivalently, $L$ is the union of finite extensions of $K$. [Wikipedia support this view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension).